# SSL cert issued to and SAN attribute

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, storage-area-network

I have added a cert to my application cacerts file. The new cert is issued to one DNS(abc.com) and they have added few other DNS(XYZ.com, TEST.com) to the SAN attribute while creating.

I tried accessing one of the DNS(XYZ.com) given in SAN attribute, it throws me the below mentioned error.

```
<Certificate chain received from XYZ.com failed hostname verification check. Certificate contained abc.com but check expected XYZ.com>
```

If we have more DNS for an application, Do we need to generate cert for every single DNS?

Comment: No, that should work. What browser/client application did you use?

Comment: I am using IE 8